# Meaning of the word prospect

Tags: vocabulary

Since one of the meanings of the word "prospect" is "chances of success". Can we say "Prospects for this mission is low"?
Does that mean that the odds of successfully completing this mission are low?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that, but you need in all cases  a plural form of both the noun and verb.

> ([OALD 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/prospect_1?q=prospect))
> **prospects** [plural] the chances of being successful
> ♦ good job/employment/career prospects
> ♦ industries with excellent growth prospects
> ♦ At 25 he was an unemployed musician with no prospects.
> ♦ prospects for something
> ♦ Long-term prospects for the economy **have** improved.
> ♦ The war undermines future prospects for economic growth.
> ♦ prospects of something
> ♦ Their prospects of success **are** slight.
> ♦ What **are** the prospects of promotion in this job?
> ♦ We are highly optimistic about the future prospects of the company.

It meaning of "odds" (used in the same way, plural) is similar, but connotes a less qualitative appreciation of the chances, the idea being more probabilistic in nature.